# assertRaises not working with Futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, concurrent.futures

I changed a call to `bar` which returned synchronously to returning a Future. When the method of `bar` actually gets executed it raises an `ValueError`.
The unit tests actually ensured that.

Now changing

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, foo.bar("/my/invalid/path"))
```

to

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, fut.result())
```

no longer is a valid assert for some reason.

The whole new code is:

```
fut = foo.bar("/my/invalid/path")
self.assertIsNotNone(fut)
self.assertRaises(ValueError, fut.result())
```

The stack trace then is:

```
"test.py", line 25, in test_load_invalid_res
self.assertRaises(ValueError, fut.result())
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
  return self.__get_result()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
  raise self._exception
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
  result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
ValueError: Could not find resource in resource path: /my/invalid/path
```

But the stack trace is actually telling me that there was a `ValueError`!? Why is it propagading beyond `assertRaises`?

EDIT:

The following code does not work:

```
try:
  fut.result()
except ValueError as e:
  pass
```

What works is e.g.:

```
try:
  fut.result()
except Exception as e:
  self.assertIsInstance(e, ValueError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the method and passing the result to `assertRaises`. Since the error happens before assertRaises is invoked, it will not catch the exception.

`assertRaises` takes a callable which it calls itself within a try/except. Your code should be:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, fut.result)
```

without the calling parens. Alternatively you can use it as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    fut.result()
```